# How to write a query to get the list of 20 highest rated books from google book API?

Tags: google-search-api

I am working with Stepzen, using Google Search Books API.
This is a query to search for books by the variable name $q entered:

```
query SearchBooks($q: String) {
    googleBooksSearch(q: $q, country: "US") {
      items {
        id
        volumeInfo {
          authors
          averageRating
          description
          imageLinks {
            thumbnail
          }
          title
          subtitle
          industryIdentifiers {
            identifier
            type
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

So how to write a query to get the list of 20 highest rated books from google book API?

I tried this query:

```
query GetTopRatedBooks {
  googleBooksSearch(q: "", country: "US", orderBy: "rating", maxResults: 20) {
    items {
      id
      volumeInfo {
        title
        subtitle
        authors
        averageRating
        ratingsCount
        description
        imageLinks {
          thumbnail
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it didn't work. It had error Unknow argument orderBy on field "Query.GoogleBooksSearch" when i run it in Stepzen Dashboard

Comment: Where do you get this API? Is there a public spec?

Comment: Yes it's public. You can get it here https://developers.google.com/books?hl=vi